# CMake ExternalProject_Add: How to build multiple msbuild targets?

Tags: c++, msbuild, cmake

I want to build a CMake ExternalProject with MSBuild. But I also just want to build a subset of the external projects solution. So basically it looks like this

```
ExternalProject_Add(MyExternalProject
  PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/External/myproject
    GIT_REPOSITORY ...
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ...
    BUILD_COMMAND msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /target:TargetA;TargetB /m Project.sln
)
```

Unfortunately CMake always replaces the `;` with a space and therefore msbuild complains that it has been given more than one project (*.sln) file.

I tried everything: quoting the arguments, putting the whole build command into a variable, escaping the semicolon... nothing worked.

Originally I also tried to build with CMake's `--build`-parameter without success.

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg16813.html hints that you need both the quotes and the escape.

Comment: I did not found a way to pass multiple targets to CMake build `--target`-parameter.

Comment: @IdeaHat, I've read the message, but I'm still not sure what should I additionally escape -- `;` or `"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add one more build instruction to `BUILD_COMMAND` option:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    MyExternalProject
    ...
    BUILD_COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build . --target TargetA
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build . --target TargetB
)
```

Comment: This works. But I get a better project build parallelism when specifying the targets in one msbuild-call.

Answer (score 1):

If you separate the targets with commas instead of semicolons it works:

```
BUILD_COMMAND msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /target:TargetA,TargetB /m Project.sln
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the ';' in the string with a different list separator, which is not affected by CMake, e.g.

```
ExternalProject_Add(MyExternalProject
  PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/External/myproject
    GIT_REPOSITORY ...
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ...
    LIST_SEPARATOR ^^
    BUILD_COMMAND msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /target:TargetA^^TargetB /m Project.sln
)
```

The "^^" is then replaced by semicolon for execution.

I found this answer here:
https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-February/049148.html